# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Tags: solidity, truffle

How to solve this error that show in the picture of chrome browser below?

Bundle.js

```
var contractABI = [];
var contractAddress = '0x9B69fA769D70728d14a70A4F10E7078032FF1632';
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:9545');
var simpleSmartContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

console.log(simpleSmartContract);

web3.eth.getAccounts()
.then(console.log);
```

truffle-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
  },
  mocha: {
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
    }
  }
}
```

[image: The error pops up in Chrome browser]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to `http://localhost:9545` while your node listens on `port: 8545`.  Thus Web3 API connection was refused.